# How to get eclipses null analyses to use assertNotNull from JUnit

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I get eclipses null analysis to work with assertNotNull from jUnit 5. In the following program I get a "Potientiel null warning" despite the fact that there is no way leaf can be null because of the assertNotNull line above.

If I change assertNotNull to assert(leaf!=null) the warning disapear.

According to this (old) link, eclipse should support working with junit asserts, and I have enabled "Enable annotation-based null analysis"

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382069

```
LeafNode leaf=getLeafMayBeNull();   assertNotNull(leaf);
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(42),leaf.getLong());
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, **for JUnit 4** the fact that after `assertNotNull(o)` `o` cannot be `null` was **hard-coded** (tracked in the [mentioned bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382069) and [implemented via this commit](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/commit/?id=340d76460697d1d853431b9a4e8d18df2a5632b9)). But **for JUnit 5** this has **not yet** been done (see in [`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.TypeConstants`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeConstants.java) the constant for [`org.junit.Assert`](https://git.eclipse.org/c/jdt/eclipse.jdt.core.git/tree/org.eclipse.jdt.core/compiler/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/compiler/lookup/TypeConstants.java#n326) but no constant for `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions`). Please report this to Eclipse.

**As workaround** you can use the following **utility method to avoid *Potential null pointer access* problems**:

```
static <T> T notNull(@Nullable T o) {
    assertNotNull(o);
    if (o == null) throw new RuntimeException();
    return o;
}
```

Using this utility method, the given snippet looks like the following:

```
LeafNode leaf = notNull(getLeafMayBeNull());
assertEquals(Long.valueOf(42),leaf.getLong());
```